# getting blank screen after some time in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, monitor

so from last two days my pc is behaving  weirdly. i am using `Ubuntu 19.10 "Eone Ermine"`. after some time working(like 30  minutes), it just gives me a blank screen with a blinking cursor. Although there's no message in the blank screen and then it gives me login screen. after logging in, all my software's (which i was working on previously) just gets closed and i have to restart my work. it's so annoying. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check `dmesg` ? when it happens login and check `dmesg` in terminal.

Comment: i  didn't checked that, but i will check that when it happens again.

Comment: i have checked ```dmesg``` in the  terminal but there's so much going on  in the terminal. in the last few line's it's says something like this:

Comment: ```[ 1827.318140] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
[ 1868.581210] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 1775.075339] [drm:fw_domains_get [i915]] *ERROR* render: timed out waiting for forcewake ack to clear.
```

Comment: You can always google the error, it seems to be an old bug https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81218/how-can-i-stop-timed-out-waiting-for-forcewake-old-ack-to-clear